# Zoom into object until it passes css/html

Tags: html, css, animation, zooming, perspective

I want to zoom into a circle(div) until it passes the "camera". I've tried perspective, but that didn't work. At least the way I used it. 
Here is my HTML:

```html
:<html>
  <body>
    <div class="test"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my css:

```css
.test{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  border:2px solid coral;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is way how you can do it without any js. But pay attention, adapt .wraper height for your own project.

For example this property helps to remove scrollbars:

`overflow: hidden;`

Also it's important that parent div need to be relative position and child div - absolute.

```css
.wraper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translateX(50%) translateY(-50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 15s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@keyframes example {
  0%   {width: 30px; height: 30px;}
  100% {width: 3000px; height: 3000px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="wraper">
  <div class="circle">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I eventually figured this out but you reminded me I could use a wrapper instead of just adding overflow:hidden; to the body

Answer (score 0):

use

```
transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
```

Comment: This certainly works to enlarge a div, but instead of just passing the camera it makes a scrollbar and stays in the screen.

Answer (score 0):

please try

```css
.test:hover{
 transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```